# Best way to store coords: struct of uints or double?

Tags: c++, variables, geo

I have geo coordinates in format N000.11.22.333 E444.55.66.777. Milliseconds are necessary for precision. I need to perform calculations like calculate coord given coord0, angle and distance.  Sure I want to keep precision not less than milliseconds. This and other calculation algorithms often use trigonometric functions to get a result.
Which solution is better: 1) use struct that contains degrees,  minutes, seconds and milliseconds as uints and overload operators for manipulate them; 2) use double type and convert coords to decimal view for calculations. As I think float type is not enough stable on these calculations.

Be used for qt 5.9 x64 project,  msvc 2017, win platform only

Comment: Why not use a library that provides a high precision floating point or fixed point format?

Comment: You'll need the values in radians anyway, if you're doing any trig calculations at all, so you might as well do the conversion ASAP for internal calculations, and only use deg/min/sec for input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick whichever is easiest (almost definitely a double).  A double is more accurate than a ruler or a careful surveyor.  Lots of navigation software uses a single 32-bit integer for lat and one for long.

Comment: But 1) I'd definitely look at the libraries @SirWojtek linked to.  2) It's a really bad idea for your datatype to matter at all at the level the coordinates are actually being used.  (You want everything running through functions designed to process coordinates).

Comment: and, lastly, this should be useful for you:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude